# Line breaks with javascript and HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a problem with Javascript and HTML.
I'm using a form that the user submits. If the credentials are wrong, the script shows a text message next to the input field.
The message contains an email which I want it to be clickable.
The things is that:
When the message is only a string, everything is OK.
When I add the `<a href=\"mailto` tag, the line breaks.

```
<div id="message_box">
<span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
</div>
```

OK:

```
$("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
        {
            var msg = ("Ooops, the number you enterd is not valid<br /> Please contact: some@mail.com to solve this problem").replace(/[\r\n]/g, '');
          $(this).html(msg).addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
        });
```

(EDIT)Shows:
 Ooops, the number you enterd is not valid
 Please contact: some@mail.com to solve this problem
[image: lines ok, the email is not clicakble]

NOT OK:

```
$("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
        {
            var msg = ("Ooops, the number you enterd is not valid<br /> Please contact: <a href=\"mailto:some@mail.com\">some@mail.com</a> to solve this problem").replace(/[\r\n]/g, '');
          $(this).html(msg).addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
        });
```

(EDIT)Shows:
   Ooops, the number you enterd is not valid
 Please contact:
some@mail.com
 to solve this problem
[image: lines broken, email clickable]

The CSS:

```
#message_box {
    width:370px;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:15px;
}



   .messagebox{
 position:relative;
 width:100px;
 margin-left:0px;
 padding:290px;
 font-size:14px;
 color: #647a03;
}
.messageboxok{
 position:relative;
 padding:0px;
 width:100px;
 color:#F00;
 font-size:10px;

}
.messageboxerror{
 position:relative;
 width:100px;
 padding:0px;
 color:#CC0000;
 font-size:12px;
}
```

Can anyone help me remove these annoying linebreaks??

Thanks!

Comment: `replace(/[\r\n]/g, '')` is unnecessary, your string contains no line breaks. I think you have to provide some screenshots.

Comment: @Sharon Haim Pour what is the css for anchor tag.

Comment: yes, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is the msgbox span:  <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>

Comment: Could still be a css rule that causes the formating.

Comment: I tried your code and it looks ok on my browser. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I also think it's a CSS rule. Could you inspect the result with firebug or chrome console? I think that in the styles section you might find some kind of weird `display` value.

Comment: @vivek: Please check the edit to see the CSS and the anchor

Comment: @Sharon - That's not *all* your CSS though, is it? You have some other rule which is setting `a { display: block; }` - fix that

Comment: @SharonHaimPour: Is that the full CSS for the page?  Or did you just copy/paste the bits you think are relevant to the messagebox?  I’m thinking there’s a rule for `<a>` elements, or for the `:link` pseudoclass somewhere.

Comment: This the complete CSS code: http://ecaliptoos-apps.com/Eci_Trivia/html/style.css

Comment: As Gareth said, you have a `a {display: block}` in your css as your second rule; that `a` tag needs to be `inline`.

Comment: See [W3C - Controlling box generation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#box-gen) & [W3C - The 'display' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)

Comment: THANK YOU!!! It works! I changed the a tag to inline both in the CSS and in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

Given the complete [CSS code](http://ecaliptoos-apps.com/Eci_Trivia/html/style.css) requested by several commenters, the `a` tag is set to `display: block`. It needs to be set to `inline` for this anchor tag.

W3C Resources:

- [Controlling box generation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#box-gen)
- [The 'display' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer would be to use CSS `white-space:nowrap;` on the `messageboxerror` class.

```
.messageboxerror {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

You could play around with `display:inline-block;` as well, and other tricks, but to me the nowrap fix should do the trick.

In this context, it's more of a workaround than a fix, so it may not fix the underlying layout problem that's causing it, but if it solves the problem there's no need to dig too much further.